# Dotted frame around the text

Tags: framed

I need to do a dotted frame, something this one: [image]

Is it possible to do?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TikZ`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[draw,dotted] {My text};
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: dotted]

Zooming in your example picture reveals that you might wish a “dashed” instead of a “dotted” frame. In this case, just replace `dotted` with `dashed`:

[image: dashed]

Answer (score 2):

EDITED to improve box corners.  I use dot `\cleaders` to make the dots.  The optional argument to `\dotbox` controls the dot spacing of the box border.

I added the 3rd example, in case the gray frame in the OP's image is actually part of the desired box, rather than just the clip field from the photo editor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verbatimbox,stackengine,graphicx,lipsum,xcolor}
\newlength\replength
\newsavebox\dtbx
\newcommand\tdotfill{\cleaders\hbox to \replength{\smash{.}}\hfill}
\def\wdbox{\kern-1pt\makebox[\dimexpr\wd\dtbx+1pt]{\tdotfill\hfil}\kern1pt}
\def\htboxraw{\makebox[\dimexpr\ht\dtbx+\dp\dtbx+3pt]{\tdotfill\hfil}}
\def\htbox{\raisebox{\dimexpr-\dp\dtbx-2pt}{\rotatebox{90}{\htboxraw}}}
\newcommand\dotbox[2][3pt]{%
  \setlength\replength{#1}%
  \savebox\dtbx{#2\kern1pt}%
  \stackunder[-.6pt]{\stackon[-1.2pt]{\htbox\usebox{\dtbx}\htbox}{\wdbox}}{\wdbox}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{verbbox}[\strut]
      print *, 'Hello World'
      stop
      end
\end{verbbox}
\dotbox{\theverbbox}

\dotbox[2pt]{\parbox{3in}{\lipsum[1]}}

{\fboxsep=1pt\fboxrule=10pt
\textcolor{black!10}{\fbox{\color{black}\dotbox{\theverbbox}}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]